# Featured Article Container with Image overlayed by Post info

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve seems relatively simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I want to have my article previews on my website appear in tiled form.

The tiles, for the sake of the argument would be a fixed height and width. Lets say 300px by 300px.

I want then for the title of the article and perhaps even a short excerpt to appear, overlaying the image. Kind of like what theverge.com have.

What I need help with is that Im just trying to do a proof of concept mock up. I can do the specific styling fine myself but its literally just the structure I cant seem to figure out.

I cant seem to get the h1 to overlay the img.

I've tried creating a parent container div, and then containing both elements within separate div containers and giving the container with the `h1` or "post info" absolute positioning.

But It never seems to work out quite right.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="feat-img">
        <img src="www.sample.com"/>
    </div>

    <div class="post-info">
        <h1>Post Title</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container: {width: 300px; height:300px;float:left;}

.feat-img img: {width:300px; height:300px; float:left;}

.post-info: {position:absolute;bottom:0px;}
```

Ok so I know there is a lot wrong with that style but I just did it off the top of my head there. It has the general jist of my train of thought.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I havent found anything (Probably becuase I dont really know what Im searching for)

Comment: This might help you. [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html) and [Source](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/)

Comment: Thanks @Surjith SM, those animations look really cool! I have them bookmarked for later use for sure,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know how an absolute div relates to a relative one.

Add

```
.feat-img {
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

to your CSS,

and place the `.post-info` div inside the `.feat-img` div:

```
<div class="feat-img">
  <div class="post-info">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
   </div>  
   <img src="image.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

apply this CSS:

```
.post-info {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px; /* or whatever position */
    left:0px; /* or whatever position */
}
```

Please have a look at this jsFiddle for a quick mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJT6f/

Cheers,

Jeroen

Comment: position: relative was the key to this! I was kicking myself for not realising this, especially since I had been putting it off for over a week now.

I just wonder though, why is it that the parent element has to be positioned relatively? I know now thats what I need to do. But why does it behave this way?

Comment: I would say `position:relative` isn't really a position, but more or less an indicator that all absolute elements nested INSIDE, will have their `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` position relative to the relative positioned element.
So `top:0;left:0` will always position the absolute position element to the left-top corner of the parent element. Not setting `position:relative` to the parent element, will cause the absolute positioned element to "snap" to the `body` left top corner (if there's no other parent element with `position:relative`.
Glad my answer helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

look on this:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xEca4/)

html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="feat-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/"/></div>
<div class="post-info"><h1>Post Title</h1></div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0}
.container: {width: 300px; height:300px; display:block; position: relative;}
.feat-img img: {width:300px; height:300px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:block;}
.post-info{position:absolute; top:130px; left:0; display:block; width:300px; height:300px; text-align: center; color:#fff;}
```

Comment: With this approach, the absolute positioned `.post-info` div won't be positioned in every tile correctly, rather all overlapping each other, since the `.feat-img` div should be relative instead of the `.container` div.